# Plotting layer given with Longitudes [0 360] to [-180 180]?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a world map in correct Longitudes from -180° to 180°. Additionally, I have a shapefile of data from South America, which shows at 290° instead of -70°. How can I reproject it using QGIS?

[image: World map and data plotted at the wrong place]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you load the South American Data into QGIS as WGS84, then `Save as ...` under a different name and `Selected CRS` `EPSG:3857 World mercator`, the shape will find its correct place in South America (supposed that On-the-fly-reprojection is active).

In a second step, you can save the World Mercator file to jet another name and `EPSG:4326`, which will reproject the data into the usual +/- 180° degree frame.

Note that this method might fail if the North or South pole is included in your data.

Answer (score 2):

All you have to do is create a new SRC with these parameters:

```
 +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +pm=360dw
```

Then you set the layer with that projection and save it with the projection that you want.