# Raster origin is incorrect so not properly overlay with vector in same CRS

Tags: raster, coordinate-system, vector

Two layers, both allegedly WGS84, one vector layer of the Midwestern US, one raster layer with coverage of the entire US. The vector layer renders correctly (coordinates are correct), but the raster layer is way off. I looked at the metadata, and the origin is set to 200,75.5 (lon,lat). The prj.aux file of the raster layer claims it is wgs84, so having my raster layer inherit the CRS of the vector layer, which is also wgs84, doesn't do anything.

How can I get these layers to properly overlay?

[image: US Raster and Midwest Vector offset]

Comment: Do the two layers appear to be precisely 360 units apart horizontally?

Comment: The right extents for the States are around (-124.731422, 24.955967) - (-66.969849, 49.371735). There is something wrong with your raster layer.

Comment: @whuber yes! Exactly 360 degrees off horizontally. The vertical coordinates appears to be in line. Any idea how to fix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@whuber pointed me in the right direction. I found my answer at [Plotting layer given with Longitudes [0 360] to [-180 180]?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109733)

I had to reproject the raster layer into World Mercator (EPSG 3395), and then load it back onto my map where OTF reprojection put it in the right spot. I tried Pseudo Mercator (EPSG 3857) and that seemed to work too.