# how to fix projection in QGIS from earth data

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, spatial-database, natural-earth

After downloading and opening natural earth data in QGIS, the result shows like this

[image]

I have tried uncheck simplify geometry but it doesn’t work. I think the problem is related with globe projections but i have never change settings or add any phyton code to do that.

sorry, may be basci but im just started with GIS softhware!

Comment: You data projection is causing the 180 degree cross-over issue - see another example here http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109733/qgis-plot-a-layer-given-with-longitudes-0-360-to-180-180

Comment: What projection are you trying to use? (What EPSG code / Custom CRS are you using for on-the-fly projection?). I think @Mapperz is right... but depending on the projection, it could also be the 'clip to hemisphere' problem (some projections like Orthographic only show one hemisphere, so you need to clip your polygons to a hemisphere. This doesn't look like Orthographic, though...)