# QGIS placing data incorrectly?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, noaa

I have two layers open.  One is a Natural Earth ocean layer, the other an output from an NOAA computer forecast model.  [The forecast model is misplaced to the east as seen in this image.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gcUprisVzYVsdZQkAtgcsS_azRk_YQXT/view?usp=sharing)

QGIS knows:

Extent

```
226.8750000000000000,9.8750000000000000 : 300.1250000000000000,55.125000000000000
```

And assigns the data to:

```
CRS USER:100025 - * Generated CRS (+proj=longlat +a=6371229 +b=6371229 +no_defs) - Projected
```

How can I move my data where it belongs?

Answer (score 2):

While your raster (NOAA grib file) is showing map in 0-360 domain, Natural Earth is on -180 - + 180. I think you basically have 2 options:

1. Choose 0-360 and modify shapefile............ For this option, see [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/79448/84455) to [Changing shapefile longitude from -180 - 180 to 0 - 360?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/79447) by [Antonio Falciano](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/22405/antonio-falciano).
2. Reproject raster to -180 - +180.................... For this option, see [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/109744/84455) to [Plotting layer given with Longitudes [0 360] to [-180 180]?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109733) by [AndreJ](https://gis.stackexchange.com/users/9159/andrej).