# Point layer from Delimited Text file added and in correct location but not displaying

Tags: qgis, point

I have some point data in a .txt with lons/lats and various measurements at each point.

I try to add the points to my project with All Layer>Add Delimited Text Layer, assign lon/lat to x/y. It apparently adds with no error, and I can tell by clicking 'zoom to layer' that it is in the correct location. (I have a basemap and know where the points should be in relation to the map)
However, it does not actually display. I have tried adding different measurements from the table to the Z value. I have tried different symbologies - single symbol, categorized etc. (Categeorized shows values categeorized in the properties but nothing on the map).

I have tried making the file smaller with fewer points in case it was too many to load.

Here is the basemap polygon, the points should show within this area. In this example they are categorized but I have tried 'single symbol' too. Symbol size is 10. Opacity is 100%, blending mode is 'normal'.
[image: Here is the basemap polygon, the points should show within this area. In this example they are categorized]

Comment: Sorry, the question is unclear to me. Why do you know that the points are "in the correct location"? Did you check with a basemap like OSM? Is the point layer maybe below the basemap and the points are thus covered? Can you add a screenshot? Without further information, any advice is just guesswork.

Comment: Because I have a polygon showing the landmass in my region of interest and 'zoom to layer' zooms in on the area I know the points should be.
The points are 'above' the map and also toggling the map on/off does not reveal the points.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot (edit your initial question and post it there).

Comment: Can you share the layer/project? Like this, it's dificult to say. With categorized style: did you click `Classify`? Sorry, without a detailed step-by-step description of exactly what you did (from the moment you loaded the layer) or uploading your date, there could be a thousend diferent reasons for your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of possible reasons why a correctly placed (point) layer doesn't show up. Check these points (cf. screenshot below):

1. Is the layer covered by another layer (e.g. basemap like OpenStreetMap)?
2. Is Layer Styling set to `Single Symbol`?
3. Is Symbol layer type set to `Simple Marker`?
4. Is `Enable symbol layer` checkbox checked?
5. Expand Layer Rendering: is `Opacity` set to 100%?
6. Check blending modes: are both modes (for Layer and Feature) set to `Normal`?
7. Is the symbol size larger then 0?
8. Is Fill color set to a color with opacity = 100%?
9. Are there any features in the layer? Check with Right click layer > Show Feature Count
10. Is the box `Live update` checked? [See more about this here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/392993/88814).

Also make sure the layer is in the correct CRS and check with a basemap **in the background** if the points appeare where they should. Right click layer > Zoom to Layer(s) to check. Often, manually "changing" the layer's CRS results in the points diappearing, so never do that. See here [for more information](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/383437/88814).

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have figured it seems to be a CRS issue I'm working on - as changing the CRS gets it to display (but now not in the correct place relative to the other layers). Thank you - I have followed your steps to eliminate it being a 'display' issue.

Comment: I solved this with help of above and following (it was a projection issue): https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109733/plotting-layer-given-with-longitudes-0-360-to-180-180

The longitudes in my text file were above >abs180. By saving layer and re-adding as EPSG 3857 it plotted correctly. (unsure why was showing correct location on 'zoom to layer' but not showing before fix)